# Gedit keyboard shortcut for "Goto Next Bookmark"?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit, plugins

I have the Gedit Bookmarks plugin activated.

The drop down "hamburger" menu has options to:

- Toggle Bookmark
- Goto Next Bookmark
- Goto Previous Bookmark

Are there keyboard shortcut for any of these, specifically the "Goto Next Bookmarks" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl+Alt+B` toggles a bookmark on/off for the current line.

`Ctrl+B` navigates to the next bookmark, moving downwards and cycling back when reaching the bottommost bookmark.

`Ctrl+Shift+B` navigates to the previous bookmark, moving upwards and cycling back when reaching the uppermost bookmark.